# Will sitting on the potty for a boy affect his standing later during pee time?

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My boy not 3 yet is fully potty trained, the problem is he's sitting on the potty even during pee time. Should I try teaching him peeing while standing or it will come naturally and just let him continue?

Comment: Out of curiosity. Would that be any problem if he sits for peeing even as an adult?

Comment: Actually I don't know. I've always thought it saves time for men, unlike we women we have to sit. Just my assumption.

Comment: Saves time, probably, but nothing more. I'd say it is much cleaner to sit. Nothing to worry about as long as he can manage social pressure.

Comment: It will come naturally. For example, his first encounter with public restrooms! Not the nice clean ones, but the ghastly horrors in between cities on the freeway, port-o-potties, somewhere deep in the woods... If he's old enough, he will realize he doesn't need to sit, and doesn't want to either

Answer (score 6):

> will come naturally and just let him continue?

You bet. If he doesn't discover it for himself, he'll sooner or later imitate other boys and men.

If it never comes naturally, trust me that you'll be very happy about it because you'll have much less cleaning up to do in the bathroom. Our boys all do it standing up and their aim leaves much to wish for, especially at night.

If I were you, I'd congratulate myself about having done a great job potty-training him.

Comment: Thanks. It was all about me noticing his face when he wanted to poop and then I'd take him to his potty, so I think it clicked to him that, that's where he should go when he wants to go. That was just it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of grown men who prefer to sit.  As a woman who sits every time, I see no reason to think it's a problem.  You are never in a bathroom that has no toilets.  There is always a toilet, so it's always an option.  My older son hates urinals because of shyness.  He doesn't sit as far as I know, but I do know he will wait as long as it takes to use a stall simply to avoid urinals.

I would bet though, he will stand when he is taller.  Many young boys aren't even tall enough to stand at a toilet.  A stool is an option, but due to lack of coordination, balancing on a stool with pants at least partially down may not feel like the safest thing to a small one, particularly standing in front of a large hard object with a pool of water inside.  My boys would stand because I used a small plastic stand alone urinal that was their size.  I didn't *want* them to stand, I just bought it as an option because I wanted any item that would encourage them to use a toilet. I am of the mindset that if they are using a toilet instead of a diaper or your floor, rejoice & don't worry about the rest.  The rest will sort itself in time.  My one son was so attached to his urinal I bought one to ship to a relative's home because we were planning to visit & he would get very upset to use anything else to pee in at that age & I just wanted a pleasant trip without toilet drama.  Her kids liked it so much I just left it as a thank you for hosting us.

Comment: *You are never in a bathroom that has no toilets. There is always a toilet, so it's always an option.*  - That's true in the US and much of Europe but it's definitely **not** universal around the world. Even in Italy I'd find bathrooms with just a place in the floor to hover over...

Comment: Yes true, traveling abroad this can be true even for women...in which case squatting could be optional for male & female as well.  I guess I more meant that you likely wouldn't ever *have* to stand if in fact someone decided they prefer not to stand upright.